# Did Charlie Duke actually get the measles?

Tags: apollo-program, astronauts, health, apollo-13

> Deke Slayton: Jim, we've got a problem. I got some blood work back from the lab. Charlie Duke has the measles.
>
> Jim Lovell: [Unconcerned] So we need a new back-up.
>
> Deke Slayton: You've all been exposed to it.
>
> Jim Lovell: Oh, I've had the measles.
>
> Deke Slayton: Ken Mattingly hasn't.

The above scene from the movie *Apollo 13* claims that Charlie Duke had a positive blood test for measles.  Did he actually get sick?  The IMDB FAQ page for the movie claims

> The movie gives the impression that the Lunar-Module-to-Command-Module reverse power transfer and subsequent power-up sequence are masterminded by Ken Mattingly. The Ken Mattingly character as portrayed in the movie is in fact a composite character representing a team of people including Charlie Duke.

which suggests that he was healthy enough to help out.  Of course, we know that Ken Mattingly was unaffected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - according to an [oral history Duke gave at NASA](https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/oral_histories/DukeCM/CMD_3-12-99.pdf), he did indeed contract the measles:

> So about, I guess, 2 weeks or 3 weeks before flight, our son Tom was
>   (let’s see now, that would be 1970)—he was 3. And he had a little
>   friend named Paul House and—who was the son of some good friends of
>   ours down in Houston. An architect. And so we were off for the weekend
>   with the Houses. And sure enough, we came back a week later and
>   Suzanne House called and said, “Paul has got the measles.” I said, “Oh
>   Lord.” **And anyway, I caught the measles from Paul, this little 3 year
>   old. And so I’m in—and I’m down there training in all this time, and
>   then, so I break out with the measles down there and, of course, go to
>   the doctor because I’m pretty sick.** And they get all excited, of
>   course. (I forgot who the flight surgeon was down there.) But anyway,
>   he gets all excited and starts testing everybody, you know, a couple
>   of weeks before the flight. And maybe it was 10 days before. Well,
>   everybody had had the measles except for Mattingly. So [James A.]
>   Lovell [Jr.] and Haise were immune, but Mattingly wasn’t. So there was
>   the big debate, you know: “What are we going to do?” And so finally
>   the decision was made, “Take Mattingly off. Put in Jack Swigert.” And
>   they could launch if they thought they were able to do that.

Comment: Welcome to *Space*.  Great answer!